# Tomcat + BIRT - requested source not available

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, reporting, birt

I am using tomcat 7 and eclipse Kepler with installed BIRT features.

When I chose new project - Dynamic Web Project. In "target runtime" I set tomcat 7, project location is c:\tomcat\webaps\projectDirectory. In "Configuration" I set "BIRT Reporting Web Project" (and in "modify" java to 1.6). Then I set to generate web.xml deployment descriptor (Content directory is: WebCOntent and Context root is folder/project name. Next I left xml configuration empty (img 1.png).

[image: 1.png]

And after running index.jsp "welcome site" is loading (img 3.png) but when I press "View Example" i get error 404 (img 2.png).

[image: 3.png]

[image: 2.png]

I attempted to find out what can be the solution but I failed. Is here someone who knows what is wrong with my configuration?

Best regards,
bez